# "Select a smart card device" in an infinite loop instead of asking for a PIN on Windows 11 - how to fix?

Tags: windows-11, smartcard

Brand new Windows 11 machine, fully up to date.

When trying to access a site using both Edge or Firefox that requires a smartcard, Windows says "select a smart card device" over and over again in an infinite loop, instead of asking for a PIN.

Without asking for a PIN, we cannot continue.

How do we get Windows 11 to ask us for a PIN as it should?

At the same time Mountain Duck works entirely fine with the smartcard and PIN, the problems start when you try access anything through a web browser.

Anyone seen this before?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.. I installed the smart card mini-drivers from yubico and restarted windows to fix it. It doesn't look like your smartcard is a yubikey but hopefully Aventra has driver that works for you.
https://www.yubico.com/support/download/smart-card-drivers-tools/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1192903)